# Unicode to integer conversion visual studio bug

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, visual-studio-2022

Im trying to convert a unicode character to an integer and encountered a bug in visual studio not sure if its a bug or something im doing wrong

The project has unicode character set and not multibyte.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr int a = L'';

    printf("%i\n", a);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Problem:
Mouse hovering variable 'a' shows that its 129408 or 0x1F980 which is correct but when it prints it out to the console i get 55358

I have created a new project and wrote the same code and it printed out the correct value but after switching the same project from unicode to multibyte and back to unicode it produces this issue, not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You told it to print as an integer when you used `%i` as your format argument.

Comment: I have tried multiple formats all of them display the same thing, I dont think this has anything to do with the format or printing to stdout since while debugging the variable a value is 55358.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wide characters in Visual Studio are only 16 bits, meaning they won't hold a value greater than 65535.  You're getting the first half of the character encoded in UTF-16, which is d83e dd80.

Comment: @bobjafari555  should turn on warnings (/W4).  `warning C4066: characters beyond first in wide-character constant ignored`.

Comment: It does seem like a bug if the debugger says the value is 129408.  `a` does only contain 55358 (0xd83e) as the warning indicates.

Comment: @MarkTolonen seems like a bug in the debugger then.  Those are rare, don't recall seeing one before.

Comment: Unclear whether hovering in the debugger or in the editor (intellisense).

Comment: The correct value is displayed while not debugging (intellisense), so how are you supposed to store these characters?

Comment: @bobjafari555 you're supposed to store them as a string, not as an integer.  It's an unfortunate accident of history that Microsoft chose an encoding that couldn't hold all the code points in a single value.

Comment: @MarkRansom that is not Microsoft's fault. When they first adopted Unicode in WinNT, UTF-16 didn't exist yet, UCS-2 was the dominant Unicode encoding at the time, and it was more than enough as Unicode hadn't exceeded UCS-2's limit yet.  Microsoft made the switch from UCS-2 to UTF-16 in Win2K, after UTF-16 had been standardized.

Comment: @RemyLebeau wasn't UCS-2 not just dominant, but the *only* available encoding when Microsoft committed to Unicode?  The perils of being an early adopter.

Comment: @MarkRansom that is true, yes